# Asynchronous read from Console.In

Tags: c#

I just realized that TextReader, the type of Console.In, doesn't have a BeginRead-method.

How would one go about to achieve asynchronous reads from Console.In?

My first idea is to get a HANDLE to stdin and get a waiter to wait for that handle to signal. But that involved a lot of Win32-calls.

Is there a more simple way to do this?
Perhaps something on the lines of:

```
Stream s = (Stream) Console.In;
s.BeginRead(..)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could do something similar to my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/23628232/659190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own class that threads the call to Console.Read and stores all the read data somewhere.  Then end the thread with the EndRead and have it return the data it's read.

Comment: That thread would be blocking on the Read-call. How do you unblock it? (Say for controlled shutdown.) Do you suggest Thread.Abort() ?
Couldn't that leave the read-from-stream in an undefined state?
/L

Comment: I personally would use a method in the class to abort the thread and then explicitly clean up the resources.  I know it's a messy solution but without a way to check for data in the stream Thread.Abort() is  the only solution I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

You can poll on `Console.KeyAvailable` in a separate thread and then read data as soon as it becomes available.