# Console ReadKey async or callback?

Tags: .net

I am trying to do a press Q to quit thing in the console window. I dont like my current implementation. Is there a way i can async or use a callback to get keys from the console?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can call `Console.ReadKey()` from another thread, so that it doesn't block your main thread. (You can use the .Net 4 `Task` or the old `Thread` to start the new thread.)

```
class Program
{
    static volatile bool exit = false;

    static void Main()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Q) ;
                exit = true;
            });

        while (!exit)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats actially what i am doing (well, the readkey part on a dif thread). This task factory looks cool. The problem with my code right now is .ReadKey seems to not return unless i bring the window to focus. Hence why i dont like my solution. When the main thread ends the other thread is still locked up. Your solution looks cool, maybe task threads will die when the main does. In that case this should work however ATM This is a 3.5 only app.

Comment: If you want the `Thread` to stop when the main thread finishes, just set `Thread.IsBackground` to `true`.

Comment: Both the code above and the IsBackground solve my problem. +1

Comment: With the task approach, you can create a new ```CancellationTokenSource```, pass the ```Token``` property to any tasks you want to be able to kill then call ```CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()``` to kill them. I'm sure everyone is aware of this 8 years later lol

Answer (score 10):

I didn't find any of the exisiting answers entirely satisfactory so I wrote my own, to work with [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and .Net 4.5.

```
/// <summary>
/// Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user
/// asynchronously. The pressed key is displayed in the console window.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cancellationToken">
/// The cancellation token that can be used to cancel the read.
/// </param>
/// <param name="responsiveness">
/// The number of milliseconds to wait between polling the
/// <see cref="Console.KeyAvailable"/> property.
/// </param>
/// <returns>Information describing what key was pressed.</returns>
/// <exception cref="TaskCanceledException">
/// Thrown when the read is cancelled by the user input (Ctrl+C etc.)
/// or when cancellation is signalled via
/// the passed <paramref name="cancellationToken"/>.
/// </exception>
public static async Task<ConsoleKeyInfo> ReadKeyAsync(
    CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    int responsiveness = 100)
{
    var cancelPressed = false;
    var cancelWatcher = new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(
        (sender, args) => { cancelPressed = true; });
    Console.CancelKeyPress += cancelWatcher;
    try
    {
        while (!cancelPressed && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                return Console.ReadKey();
            }

            await Task.Delay(
                responsiveness,
                cancellationToken);
        }

        if (cancelPressed)
        {
            throw new TaskCanceledException(
                "Readkey canceled by user input.");
        }

        throw new TaskCanceledException();
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress -= cancelWatcher;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I made it:

```
// Comments language: pt-BR
// Aguarda key no console
private static async Task<ConsoleKey> WaitConsoleKey ( ) {
    try {
        // Prepara retorno
        ConsoleKey key = default;
        // Aguarda uma tecla ser pressionada
        await Task.Run ( ( ) => key = Console.ReadKey ( true ).Key );
        // Retorna a tecla
        return key;
    }
    catch ( Exception ex ) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. This is the best solution on the page in terms of concisely adhering to contemporary `async` sensibility. For example, it importantly points out that `Task.Run(…)` has special built-in knowledge of modern compiler-generated lightweight `async` methods, which allows it to distinguish those from legacy `ThreadPool`- or `TaskContinuationSource`-backed `Task`-returning methods. The distinction is important for keeping `Console` apps alive; less-sophisticated code will prematurely exit on the (ostensible) "completion" of the continuation `Task` returned from the top-level `async` method.

Comment: Why the try catch with a rethrow of the same exception?

Comment: @JohnHamm thats because, at the time, I had a log there, so I took it out and replaced with that throw, but that's totally removable. 

Comment: This can be made more concise again by doing `private static Task<ConsoleKey> WaitConsoleKey() => Task.Run(() => Console.ReadKey(true).Key);`

Answer (score 6):

You can use the KeyAvailable property (Framework 2.0) :

```
if (System.Console.KeyAvailable)
{
   ConsoleKeyInfo key = System.Console.ReadKey(true);//true don't print char on console
   if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
   {
       //Do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation that I created using `KeyAvailable`. This keeps a prompt at the bottom of the console window while everything "printed" to the console starts from the top.

```
public class Program
{
    private static int consoleLine;
    private static int consolePromptLine;
    private static bool exit;
    static string clearLine = new string(' ', Console.BufferWidth - 1);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder commandCapture = new StringBuilder(10);
        string promptArea = "Command> ";

        consolePromptLine = Console.WindowTop + Console.WindowHeight - 1;

        ClearLine(consolePromptLine);
        Console.Write(promptArea);

        while (!exit)
        {
            // Do other stuff

            // Process input
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                var character = Console.ReadKey(true);

                if (character.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    if (commandCapture.Length != 0)
                    {
                        ProcessCommand(commandCapture.ToString());
                        commandCapture.Clear();
                        ClearLine(consolePromptLine);
                        Console.Write(promptArea);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (character.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
                    {
                        if (commandCapture.Length != 0)
                        {
                            commandCapture.Remove(commandCapture.Length - 1, 1);
                            ClearLine(consolePromptLine);
                            Console.Write(promptArea);
                            Console.Write(commandCapture.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        commandCapture.Append(character.KeyChar);
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, consolePromptLine);
                        Console.Write(promptArea);
                        Console.Write(commandCapture.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void ProcessCommand(string command)
    {
        if (command == "start")
        {
            Task<string> testTask = new Task<string>(() => { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000); return "Test Complete"; });

            testTask.ContinueWith((t) => { Print(t.Result); }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
            testTask.Start();
        }
        else if (command == "quit")
        {
            exit = true;
        }

        Print(command);
        consolePromptLine = Console.WindowTop + Console.WindowHeight - 1;
    }

    public static void Print(string text)
    {
        ClearLine(consoleLine);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        consoleLine = Console.CursorTop;
    }

    public static void ClearLine(int line)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, line);
        Console.Write(clearLine);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Helper class. Provides a `CancellationToken` that is cancelled when the 'Esc' key is pressed. Stops reading the console keys when it is disposed.

```cs
sealed class EscapeKeyToken : IDisposable
{
  private readonly CancellationTokenSource _disposed = new();
  private readonly CancellationTokenSource _escapeKeyPressed = new();

  public CancellationToken Token => _escapeKeyPressed.Token;

  public EscapeKeyToken()
  {
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
      try
      {
        while (true)
        {
          if (Console.KeyAvailable)
          {
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
              _escapeKeyPressed.Cancel();
              return;
            }
          }

          await Task.Delay(100, _disposed.Token);
        }
      }
      catch { }
    });
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    _disposed.Cancel();
    _disposed.Dispose();
    _escapeKeyPressed.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
  var choice = Console.ReadKey();
  Console.WriteLine();

  switch (choice.Key)
  {
    case ConsoleKey.D1:
    {
      using var escapeKeyToken = new EscapeKeyToken();
      Console.WriteLine("1: Push data synchronization in progress. Reading remote data cache to see what's there. This will take a while.");
      Console.Write("Press the 'Esc' key to cancel the operation.");
      await PushData(escapeKeyToken.Token);
      Console.WriteLine("Push data complete.");
      break;
    }

    case ConsoleKey.D2:
    {
      using var escapeKeyToken = new EscapeKeyToken();
      Console.WriteLine("2: Pull data synchronization in progress. Reading remote data cache to see what's there. This will take a while.");
      Console.Write("Press the 'Esc' key to cancel the operation.");
      await PullData(escapeKeyToken.Token);
      break;
    }

    default:
      Console.WriteLine("Choose 1 or 2.");
      Console.WriteLine();
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking from all the answers here, this is my version:

```
public class KeyHandler
{
    public event EventHandler KeyEvent;

    public void WaitForExit()
    {
        bool exit = false;
        do
        {
            var key = Console.ReadKey(true); //blocks until key event
            switch (key.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Q:
                    exit = true;
                    break;
               case ConsoleKey.T:
                    // raise a custom event eg: Increase throttle
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (!exit);
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var worker = new MyEventDrivenClassThatDoesCoolStuffByItself();
    worker.Start();

    var keyHandler = new KeyHandler();
    keyHandler.KeyEvent+= keyHandler_KeyEvent; // modify properties of your worker
    keyHandler.WaitForExit();
}
```

- It doesn't require Main to do anything in a loop, allowing it to simply orchestrate between handling keys and manipulating properties of the worker class.
- Taking the hint from @Hans, the KeyHandler doesn't need to async up a new thread since Console.ReadKey blocks until a key is received.

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-blocking solution using asynchronous code and cancellation tokens. This method works well when you have some heavy tasks running but want the app to quit responsively when a key is pressed.

```
// Set up the asynchronous key reader, but don't block.
_ = WaitForKey(cancellationTokenSource);

try
{
    for(;;)
    {
        // Code running in an infinite loop
        await MyTaskAsync(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}
catch(TaskCanceledException)
{
    // When a key is pressed, we'll end up here
}
finally
{
    // Clean up
}   

async Task WaitForKey(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
{
    // You could filter on a specific character or key combination in this method, such as the OP's 'q' character
    await ReadKeyAsync();
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}

async Task<ConsoleKeyInfo> ReadKeyAsync(bool intercept = true) => await Task.Run(() => Console.ReadKey(intercept));
```