# Is there any equvalent builtin async method to Console.ReadKey()?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, mono, class-library

I was writing a simple console application in C#.

I could not find any equivalent async method for Console.ReadKey() in `Console.In` or anywhere else in System or System.Core Assembly.

Is there any **builtin** function to ReadKey from Stdout asynchronously?

> I have used C# 7.3 in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and .NET Core 2.1. but the question is for any current or future version of C# in any platform like .NET Framework, .NET Core, Mono etc.

---

> Note for **Expert** Only: I know, how to implement it manually, and hence, I don't need any *sample code* for it. Also, I am not interested to add any additional library for this **right now**. I have just asked for an information not for a workaround.

Comment: [Here's an open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25036) for this. Given the issue is still open, I doubt that there's currently an implementation in the standard library.

Comment: Why exactly would you want that?  A console does not have a SyncContext so the only benefit would be to free up 1 thread, application wide?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no natural way in C# that helps you to do it. For solving this problem, I've tried 2 ways below:

1. Implementing a **keyboard hook**. See at [MSDN Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4298bb86-1286-48d7-919a-e32c35eab766/asynchronous-keyboard-checking?forum=csharpgeneral) for reference.
2. Calling `Console.ReadKey()` from another process. [Ref on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3382426/5704834)

Based on your situation, you could choose one.